# zsh completion: complete _values, but case-insensitive

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, case-sensitivity

I have the following completion script to complete a list of roles:

```
host /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions # cat _foo
#compdef foo

local -a values=('ROLE_ADMIN[Admin]' 'ROLE_USER[User]')

_values -s , 'roles' $values
```

This works fine so far; it'll complete the roles:

```
host ~ # foo ROLE_<TAB>
roles
ROLE_ADMIN  -- Admin
ROLE_USER   -- User
```

But I want the completion to work case-insensitively, ie. if I type now type `ad` after `ROLE_`, I want it to complete `ROLE_ADMIN`, which doesn't work.

I've figured out that I need to use `compadd -M` with a match-spec like `'m:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]}'`, but I can't figure out how to pass this to `_values` which doesn't seem to support `-M`.

Answer (score 1):

`_values` indeed can't do this, but the problem is easily circumvented by replacing `_values` with `_sequence _describe` to get the value completion manually, and `_describe` does support the `-M` option:

```
host /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions # cat _foo2
#compdef foo2

local -a values=('ROLE_ADMIN:Admin' 'ROLE_USER:User')

_sequence _describe 'roles' values -M 'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]}'
```

Note that `_describe` requires the descriptions in a slightly different format - `word:desc` instead of `word[desc]`.

Now it'll complete case-insensitively as expected:

```
host ~ # foo2 ROLE_ad<TAB>
host ~ # foo2 ROLE_ADMIN,
```

Comment: Big thanks to [llua](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11759/llua) who actually came up with this solution when I asked for help in the #zsh IRC channel with this.